# Laravel Edit Page Content using CKeditor

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, ckeditor

I'm building a dynamic website in which the content can be edit from the admin panel and the content is stored in the database.

I'm using CKEditor to edit the content, I did load the content of the page from the database to the editor but the content doesn't appear as it supposes to. I mean the style of the content is so messed up in the editor

I think it's something related to CSS

**Migration**

```
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('keyword');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->text('content')->nullable();
```

**View**

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @if ($message = Session::get('error'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                    </button>
                    <span>
                      <b> Error - </b> {{ $message }}</span>
                </div>

            @endif
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card ">
                        <form method="post" action="{{ route('pages.store') }}" class="form-horizontal" id="TypeValidation">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PATCH')
                            <div class="card-header card-header-rose card-header-text">
                                <div class="card-text">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Edit Page</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body ">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="About Us Page Title">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Keywords</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" value="Washington DC,Academy" class="form-control tagsinput" name="keyword" data-role="tagsinput" data-color="info" placeholder="Add">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" maxlength="160" aria-required="true">                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea name="content_en" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                                                {{$about->content}}
                                            </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-right">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rose">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{asset('assets/js/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        CKEDITOR.config.defaultLanguage = 'en';
    </script>
@endsection
```

So, Have you got any idea to do this?

Comment: welcome to SO ... try `{{$about->content}}` to `{!! $about->content !!}`

Comment: I already tried it give me the same results